# Android - default target additional emulator command line options

Tags: android, emulation

I need somebodies help.
I deleted the default "Additional Emulator Command Line Option" Line that was there, now my HOME never starts up on the Android device.

If anybody can please post the line that they have...
Debug Arrow -> Debug Configurations... -> select the [TARGET] tab -> scroll to the bottom

Please, will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" are empty by default.
Sometimes, I some options for proxy-servers or partition size, but I have to add them by myself, by default this is empty.
If your problem is still there, maybe remove and reconfigure your run/debug configuration.
When you run on a simulator, maybe it's also a good idea to delete the emulator in the AVD manager and create a new one.
When you run on a device, sometimes it may help to reboot the device.

Good luck.

Have a nice development.

Kr